# Write a xml file and force to download with php

Tags: php, xml

The below code is not working to prompt download of a xml file. How do I set the header before the $data, since i am getting the below warning:
“Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by”

```
private function display() {
$data ="some string";
$my_file = "sample.xml"; // name of file to be downloaded
$handle = fopen($my_file, "w");
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($my_file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($my_file));
readfile($my_file);
exit;
}
Here is my ajax function
$.ajax({
url: "webservices/rest_api/display",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have whitespaces in you file name? Try encapsulating your filename  in doulbe quotes like so:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($my_file).'"');
```

as the example on php.net : http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: No Louis that does not seem to work. Thanks for the quick response!!